# Parsing a json string to get the same kind of object jQueries getJSON method provides

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to use a jquery mapping tool (gmaps) to render a Google Map and need to parse JSON data to it.   I'm working from some sample code which loads the json data to use from a remote url.

The sample code works great when I replicate it.  To load the remote data it uses the jquery getJSON method as follows.

```
var xhr = $.getJSON('https://coffeemaker.herokuapp.com/foursquare.json?q[near]=Lima,%20PE&q[query]=Ceviche')
```

The difference I want to make is that my data won't be at a remote url, it will be hard coded into my html page.

To test this out, using the string I get if I surf to the remote JSON url above I've tried pasting this into the same variable using the JavaScript JSON.Parse function

```
 var xhr = JSON.parse(('{"venues":[{"id":"52  etc...
```

But this doesn't work and I don't get the same object that the remote getJSON function returns.

If I do a console.log() of the working returned remote data I see:

> Object {readyState: 1}

Whereas my hard coded string that is JSON.parsed returns

> Object {venues: Array[30], geocode: Object}

I'm sure this is something fairly simple on my part, any ideas?

Comment: I am confused. So which one is not working? The variable with the pasted JSON or the one using `$.getJSON()`?

Comment: the one with the pasted json isn't working.  To clarify, its exactly the same JSON from the remote url.

Comment: But if you are getting `Object {venues: Array[30], geocode: Object}` it seems to me _it is_ in fact working.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify your doubts. https://jsfiddle.net/mqybdd6g/

Comment: Well yes JSON.parse is working, but it isn't returning the data in the same format as getJSON does.

Comment: Yeah, getJSON returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. `JSON.parse` returns an object. Once you access the data, it should be virtually the same.

Comment: Yes I understand my use of JSON.parse isn't what is required here, getJSON returns data as a plainobject from what I've read.  And so if I have a JSON string (the same one that this remote url provides) I need to convert that into an object, so if I don't use JSON.parse what can I use ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129177/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-adamjones).

Answer (score 0):

Those are two completely different functions.

While JSON.parse only parses the json string and constructs an object with the data, $.getJSON loads JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request and returns a ["jqXHR" object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object).

That means you have to look further down the code and see if it uses any of the interface that jqXHR object provides and if you need it or not.

Comment: Hi @Algirdas thanks for the comment.  The sample code I'm using virtually unmodified is here: https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/json.html   I can't see any interface of jqXHR

Comment: As i can see, these lines are where your modified code should crash:

Comment: jqXHR object has a method "done" (for when the request is finished), while the object JSON.parse does not.

Comment: What you could do is this:  var json_data = JSON.parse(('{"venues":[{"id":"52  etc...) ; printResults(json_data); loadResults(json_data);

Comment: Sorry, how is that different to what I mentioned doing ?

Comment: Note my last two lines -> printResults and loadResults. if you use JSON.parse, you have to call those methods yourself and not use xhr.done method.

Comment: You have to change those lines aswel if you want your code with JSON.parse to work.